# How can I make the following show ONLY Instances > 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query in a stored procedure that generates a temp table.

I need it to show only Applications that have more than 1 rows AND I need a row for each of those duplicate entries.

This is what I have so far, how can I make it work?

```
    Select  t2.ApplicationName, t3.MainframeDev, t3.MainframeTest, t3.MMX,       
            t3.HMG, t3.WMI, t3.TJXE, 'Changing' as UsedAs, t3.ProjectName, 
            t4.FirstName+'  '+LastName as ProjectLead,t3.Status,  
            CONVERT(varchar(20),t3.ImplementationDate,126) as ImplementationDate
    from    ImpactedApplications t1 
    inner join Applications t2 on t2.AppID = t1.AppID 
    inner join Projects t3 on t3.ProjectID = t1.ProjectID
    inner join Employees t4 on t3.ProjectLead = t4.EmpId
    where t2.ApplicationName <> 'NA' 


    UNION

    Select  t2.ApplicationName, t3.MainframeDev, t3.MainframeTest, t3.MMX, 
            t3.HMG, t3.WMI, t3.TJXE, 'Supporting' as UsedAs, t3.ProjectName, 
            t4.FirstName+' '+LastName as ProjectLead,t3.Status, 
            CONVERT(varchar(20),t3.ImplementationDate,126) as ImplementationDate
    from SupportingApplications t1 
    inner join Applications t2 on t2.AppID = t1.AppID
    inner join Projects t3 on t3.ProjectID = t1.ProjectID
    inner join Employees t4 on t3.ProjectLead = t4.EmpId
    where t2.ApplicationName <> 'NA'
    Order By ApplicationName, MainframeDev, UsedAs ASC
```

Expected Output would have the applications with the relevant info from the Select Query above ordered something like below:

```
ApplicationName1 
ApplicationName1 
ApplicationName1 
ApplicationName2 
ApplicationName2 
ApplicationName2 
ApplicationName3
ApplicationName3
```

Comment: @havenodisplayname Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all duplicate rows or All applications those have multiple entries, then I think You need only Group By Clause and Having Clause to solve this.

Put the output of your query in Temp Table Say `#application`, then

```
Create table #application(appid int, aapvname varchar(50))
insert into #application values (1,'100'),(1,'101'),(2,'200'),(2,'201'),(3,'300'),(4,'400')

Select * 
From #application
WHERE appid IN (
                 Select appid 
                 From #application
                 GROUP BY appid
                 Having COUNT(*) > 1)
```

**<kbd>[Working SQL FIDDLE Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f04e5/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your base tables, this is somewhat a shot in the dark:

```
;WITH
    cte1 AS (
        Select  t2.ApplicationName, t3.MainframeDev, t3.MainframeTest, t3.MMX,       
                t3.HMG, t3.WMI, t3.TJXE, 'Changing' as UsedAs, t3.ProjectName, 
                t4.FirstName+'  '+LastName as ProjectLead,t3.Status,  
                CONVERT(varchar(20),t3.ImplementationDate,126) as ImplementationDate
        from    ImpactedApplications t1 
        inner join Applications t2 on t2.AppID = t1.AppID 
        inner join Projects t3 on t3.ProjectID = t1.ProjectID
        inner join Employees t4 on t3.ProjectLead = t4.EmpId
        where t2.ApplicationName <> 'NA' 

        UNION

        Select  t2.ApplicationName, t3.MainframeDev, t3.MainframeTest, t3.MMX, 
                t3.HMG, t3.WMI, t3.TJXE, 'Supporting' as UsedAs, t3.ProjectName, 
                t4.FirstName+' '+LastName as ProjectLead,t3.Status, 
                CONVERT(varchar(20),t3.ImplementationDate,126) as ImplementationDate
        from SupportingApplications t1 
        inner join Applications t2 on t2.AppID = t1.AppID
        inner join Projects t3 on t3.ProjectID = t1.ProjectID
        inner join Employees t4 on t3.ProjectLead = t4.EmpId
        where t2.ApplicationName <> 'NA'
    ), cte2 AS (
        SELECT      *, AppCount = COUNT(ApplicationName) OVER (PARTITION BY ApplicationName)
        FROM        cte1
    )

SELECT  *
FROM    cte2
WHERE   AppAcount > 1
```